# Keeping radio button checked after form submit

Tags: radio-button

I have two radio buttons and when user clicks on one radio button and clicks button it should stay selected. But what is happening is only last one remains selected even if I select and search with first radio button.

My code:

```
<input type="radio" <?php if(isset($_POST['gender']) && isset($_POST['gender']) == 'male') echo "checked='checked'"; ?> name="gender" id="male" value="male" onclick="getGender(this.value);" /><strong>Groom</strong>
              <input type="radio" <?php if(isset($_POST['gender']) && isset($_POST['gender']) == 'female') echo "checked='checked'"; ?> name="gender" id="female" value="female" onclick="getGender(this.value);" /><strong>Bride</strong>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
&& isset($_POST['gender']) == 'male')
```

to

```
&& ($_POST['gender'] == 'male')
```

and do the same for female